Assistance Requested for Microphone Configuration on Lenovo 700 Ultraportable Bluetooth Speaker
I am currently using the Lenovo 700 Ultraportable Bluetooth Speaker, which comes with an embedded microphone, on a system running Ubuntu 20.04. While the speaker functions perfectly as an output device, the microphone does not get detected. The microphone works only when Bluetooth is enabled; however, my goal is to use the microphone without relying on Bluetooth.
Additionally, when I run the command arecord -l, the microphone does not appear in the list of recording devices. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue

Is there anyone can help ?
